# mysql: SELECT WHERE id IN() and others

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using this query to select a set of records from a MySQL database:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id IN(10,14,12,11,8,7,4) 
  AND actief='on' 
ORDER BY FIELD(id,10,14,12,11,8,7,4)
```

This will give me the given ID's. In this case I will get a maximum of 7 records. But it can be less if for example ID '14' has active='off'.

But what I need is a set of 20 records where het list `IN(10,14,12,11,8,7,4)` **must** be in the result if they also meet the condition `active='on'`. If this returns 6 records, then I want the query to select another 14 records. Selecting highest ID first, must meet `active='on'` and may not already be in the result.

Can this be achieved by one SQL statement. Or should I first put the result of the mentionend query in an array and in a second array select the remaining records. And finaly put those also in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sort rather than filter the results.  I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
ORDER BY (id IN(10,14,12,11,8,7,4) AND actief = 'on') desc,
         FIELD(id,10,14,12,11,8,7,4),
         id desc
LIMIT 20;
```

EDIT:

The final solution only wanted `actief = 'on'`, so:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE actief = 'on'
ORDER BY (id IN (10,14,12,11,8,7,4)) desc,
         FIELD(id,10,14,12,11,8,7,4),
         id desc
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: This will only return records with the given ID's that match `active='on'`.

Comment: @Timo002 . . . Not now.  I removed the `where` clause.

Comment: @Gordan Linoff, I made another small change to the query because in your query, all other records are not matched to `actief='on'`. So I added a WHERE condition `WHERE actief='on'` and removed it from the ORDER BY. Full query: `SELECT * FROM p_headsets WHERE actief='on' ORDER BY (id IN(10,14,12,11,8,7,4) AND actief='on') desc, FIELD(id,10,14,12,11,8,7,4), id desc LIMIT 20`
This works great!